# Trying to re-attach CIFS ISO share, XenServer SR_BACKEND_FAILURE_222

Tags: virtual-machines, xenserver, cifs

My CIFS mount for ISOs stopped working recently. I tried to detatch it and re-attach it, however I get the following error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2529G.jpg

I tried looking this error up, however I cannot conclusively determine what is failing. I have restarted the host xenserver as well as the host serving the target. So far as I can tell this is the only issue that is observed with our CIFS mounts. Furthermore, I tried manually unmounting the target at the CLI, but I don't recall the exact method I used.

xenserver 6.0.0-50762p

I do not know what exactly caused this issue as other services have not been affected.

Comment: I think I'm just going to upgrade my version of xenserver. I cannot find a solution to this problem anywhere. :(

Comment: Have you tried to just destroy the sr and recreate it?

Comment: Hey sorry about this, it turns out it was an auth issue. I was not properly authenticating. Once I got a functional account it worked right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a permission issue on the share end. I was not using the correct credentials. I needed to use an Active Directory account and once I did it was resolved.